# Instance variable in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I define an instance variable in an action, is it not available inside other actions belonging to same controller.

Instance variable should be available throughout the class. Right?

```
    class DemoController < ApplicationController

  def index
    #render('demo/hello')
    #redirect_to(:action => 'other_hello')

  end

  def hello
    #redirect_to('http://www.google.co.in')
    @array = [1,2,3,4,5]
    @page = params[:page].to_i
  end

  def other_hello
    render(:text => 'Hello Everyone')
  end

end
```

If I define the array in *index* and access it from *hello* view then why am I getting errors for false values of nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance variables are available only during the request (controller and view rendering), because Rails create a new instance of controller for each request.

If you want to keep data between request, use [sessions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session).

Answer (score 0):

If you define an instance variable in the `index` action, it will only be available in that action. If you want to define the same instance variable for two actions, you can do one of two things:

```
def index
  set_instance_array
  ...
end

def hello
  set_instance_array
  ...
end

...

private
def set_instance_array
  @array = [1,2,3,4,5]
end
```

If you're doing this a lot, you could use a before filter:

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_instance_array

  def index
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

This would call the set_instance_array method before every request.  See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters for more info.